# Travelling long-distance (Winnipeg – Auckland) with several stops as a blind person

Tags: air-travel, accessibility

I am 100% blind and am considering traveling to Auckland by myself to visit a friend this February.
Since being almost 24 hours on a plane non-stop directly from Vancouver to Auckland does not do it for me, I’m going to try to pick a cost-effective flight route, so I can make some stops and get off the plane.
I’d like to do something like going from Winnipeg to Toronto, Toronto to Frankfurt, Frankfurt to Cape Town, then from there either go directly to Auckland or go to Johannesburg, then Johannesburg to Auckland, or something like that where I make a few stops.

My question is, given that I’d be stopping in several cities on a couple continents, how would a trip like this work for a blind person such as myself?
Surely a blind person like me should be able to get help.
I want to try to avoid having to take Henrietta along with me, since that means I'd have to pay for her ticket as well, as her hotel and food and such, not to mention she likes to stop all the time.

What is your best solution in getting to Auckland while making several stops in terms of accessibility?
Also what types of stops would you recommend for me to make on this trip?
Is my plan good?

henrietta is my girlfriend, and I'd like a few stops that last anywhere for a few minutes to a few hours, so I can at least get off the plane and stretch.  I've done 14 hour buss trips with my GF with no stops and it was hell, so I'd like a couple stops at least, even if it's not the exact route I mention above.

Comment: Have you done less ambitious trips solo?

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan I've been to D.C. by myself.

Comment: I think in a similar situation, I would fly Vancouver to Hawaii, then to NZ or Australia. Flight time from Hawaii to Sydney is around 10 hours, for example.

Comment: The route you suggest is [more than twice as far (distance wise)](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=YWG-YVR-AKL,YWG-YTO-FRA-CPT-JNB-SYD-AKL) as the most direct route. Johannesburg to Auckland alone is the same distance as Winnipeg to Auckland. It’s probably going to be significantly more than twice as expensive because this isn’t a natural route; there will be little competition. It’s also simply bound to go wrong and require proactive work on your part to repair. This is a completely different type of trip to a quick hop to D.C. I really would consider just taking the most direct route you can.

Comment: When I few to NZ (from Europe) one of the best options was to fly to LA, (USA) and flying to Auckland from there. I am surprised you even consider flying to Europe, South Africa. A one stop travel will be much easier to manage and your route allows for that with several good options.

Comment: I love all your suggestions.  I may consider Hawaii one.  I just remember a friend of mine stopping in Johannesburg, hence where I came up with that one.  the reason why I'm not doing the directl flight from Vancouver to Sydney is because it's like 20 hours on a plane all in one. I can do 8 to 10 hours, but not 20 hours.

Comment: I always thought Cape Town to Sydney would be a good route because of the fact that ships stopped in cape Town going from Sydney to a European city such as London or Copenhagen.  Pluss planes tend to use the poles all the time.  guess I was wrong. darn you Angie for making me thing that route would work.

Comment: @mkennedy I like your suggestion a lot.  cuts it in half almost.

Comment: @mkennedy I concur, I did this myself a few years ago, it can be both cheap and comfy: premium economy from Vancouver to Hawaii and then Jetstar business down.

Comment: FYI, Vancouver to Auckland nonstop is 14 hours, hardly "almost 24".  Also keep in mind that a widebody airliner is quite different from a bus; it's a lot easier to stand up, stretch and walk around on a large plane than a bus.

Comment: It appears over 24 hours on the calendar because of the International Date Line.

Comment: Not only is the direct flight 14 hours, but even stopping in Hawaii still leaves 9 hours in the second leg and on the dates I happened to throw at it caused the tickets to be three times as expensive and on separate tickets also--very dangerous because a late flight likely simply destroys your second ticket.  As an experienced, sighted traveler I wouldn't consider such a flight.

Comment: Qantas via Los Angeles does not look too bad and it's all on one ticket- Westjet handles the North American bits with a Qantas codeshare.  If you want to avoid the US for some reason you could look at flying Air China from Vancouver via Beijing but you would have to overnight in Beijing, which I would not suggest as a first choice.

Comment: I will take all of your suggestions as well as patricia's answer below into consideration.  if you all have more suggestions lay them on me, this is quite helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than beginning by selecting a route, I suggest working on selecting an airline.

Your best chance for good support at each change is to fly on a single ticket. First select airlines that fly between your end-points, including codeshare and partner airline flights. Ask them about their assistance for blind passengers. Search on-line for reviews of their services by other blind passengers.

Almost certainly, once you have picked an airline you will know your route. If not, you can ask for advice about which changes will be easier and better supported.